# Native crash Android OS 8

Tags: android

App stops work due to native crash. Based on the logs I can't reproduce this issue and all my attempts were unsuccessful. It happens on Android OS 8 and 8.1 on specific devices.

Dependencies:

```
       implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
       implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.3'
       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
       implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.15'
```

Stack trace:

```
    #00  pc 000000000001e658  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+120)
    #01  pc 00000000004731a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+552)
    #02  pc 000000000056b040  /system/lib64/libart.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+964)
    #03  pc 00000000000e1264  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::MemMapArena::MemMapArena(unsigned long, bool, char const*)+332)
    #04  pc 00000000000e1664  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArenaPool::AllocArena(unsigned long)+236)
    #05  pc 00000000000e1f20  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArenaAllocator::AllocFromNewArena(unsigned long)+36)
    #06  pc 0000000000149870  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInstructionBuilder::Build()+1248)
    #07  pc 000000000011c8c8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HGraphBuilder::BuildGraph()+132)
    #08  pc 0000000000143de8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryBuildAndInlineHelper(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, bool, art::HInstruction**)+2616)
    #09  pc 0000000000141a5c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryBuildAndInline(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, art::HInstruction**)+1376)
    #10  pc 000000000013d2b0  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInlineAndReplace(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, bool, bool)+104)
    #11  pc 000000000013c688  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInline(art::HInvoke*)+1096)
    #12  pc 000000000013c038  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::Run()+572)
    #13  pc 0000000000146858  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::RunOptimizations(art::HGraph*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::DexCompilationUnit const&)+796)
    #14  pc 0000000000144094  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryBuildAndInlineHelper(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, bool, art::HInstruction**)+3300)
    #15  pc 0000000000141a5c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryBuildAndInline(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, art::HInstruction**)+1376)
    #16  pc 000000000013d2b0  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInlineAndReplace(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, bool, bool)+104)
    #17  pc 000000000013c688  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInline(art::HInvoke*)+1096)
    #18  pc 000000000013c038  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::Run()+572)
    #19  pc 0000000000146858  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::RunOptimizations(art::HGraph*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::DexCompilationUnit const&)+796)
    #20  pc 0000000000144094  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryBuildAndInlineHelper(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, bool, art::HInstruction**)+3300)
    #21  pc 0000000000141a5c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryBuildAndInline(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, art::HInstruction**)+1376)
    #22  pc 000000000013d2b0  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInlineAndReplace(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, bool, bool)+104)
    #23  pc 000000000013c688  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInline(art::HInvoke*)+1096)
    #24  pc 000000000013c038  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::Run()+572)
    #25  pc 0000000000146858  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::RunOptimizations(art::HGraph*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::DexCompilationUnit const&)+796)
    #26  pc 0000000000144094  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryBuildAndInlineHelper(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, bool, art::HInstruction**)+3300)
    #27  pc 0000000000141a5c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryBuildAndInline(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, art::HInstruction**)+1376)
    #28  pc 000000000013d2b0  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInlineAndReplace(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, bool, bool)+104)
    #29  pc 000000000013c688  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInline(art::HInvoke*)+1096)
    #30  pc 000000000013c038  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::Run()+572)
    #31  pc 0000000000146858  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::RunOptimizations(art::HGraph*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::DexCompilationUnit const&)+796)
    #32  pc 0000000000144094  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryBuildAndInlineHelper(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, bool, art::HInstruction**)+3300)
    #33  pc 0000000000141a5c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryBuildAndInline(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, art::HInstruction**)+1376)
    #34  pc 000000000013d2b0  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInlineAndReplace(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ReferenceTypeInfo, bool, bool)+104)
    #35  pc 000000000013ea80  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInlineMonomorphicCall(art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*, art::Handle<art::mirror::ObjectArray<art::mirror::Class>>)+408)
    #36  pc 000000000013d9d0  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInlineFromInlineCache(art::DexFile const&, art::HInvoke*, art::ArtMethod*)+768)
    #37  pc 000000000013c864  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::TryInline(art::HInvoke*)+1572)
    #38  pc 000000000013c038  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::HInliner::Run()+572)
    #39  pc 0000000000188ff4  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::MaybeRunInliner(art::HGraph*, art::CodeGenerator*, art::CompilerDriver*, art::DexCompilationUnit const&, art::PassObserver*, art::VariableSizedHandleScope*) const+192)
    #40  pc 000000000018b0dc  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::RunOptimizations(art::HGraph*, art::CodeGenerator*, art::CompilerDriver*, art::DexCompilationUnit const&, art::PassObserver*, art::VariableSizedHandleScope*) const+6332)
    #41  pc 000000000018c510  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::TryCompile(art::ArenaAllocator*, art::CodeVectorAllocator*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, unsigned int, art::InvokeType, unsigned short, unsigned int, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>, art::DexFile const&, art::Handle<art::mirror::DexCache>, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::VariableSizedHandleScope*) const+2912)
    #42  pc 000000000018e128  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::JitCompile(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitCodeCache*, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::jit::JitLogger*)+976)
    #43  pc 0000000000109244  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::jit::JitCompiler::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, bool)+160)
    #44  pc 000000000031be60  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::CompileMethod(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, bool)+452)
    #45  pc 000000000031e4a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::JitCompileTask::Run(art::Thread*)+620)
    #46  pc 00000000004b2d24  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+88)
    #47  pc 00000000004b281c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+148)
    #48  pc 0000000000077974  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    #49  pc 000000000001fa3c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar crash and unfortunately I'm not so strong to fix it but I guess it's related to a memory outage. Here there are some useful indication to analyze and debug your case: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash
Hope it can help if not already fixed. Good luck